# i18next detectLngFromPath not working

Tags: javascript, i18next

i am trying to set up i18n on my project (using express.js), right now trying to make work [i18next](http://i18next.com/node/index.html) package, so that myproject.com/en/other/path/ shows to english and myproject.com/ee/other/path shows Latvian text.
But the module doesn't seem to detect language from path. At first i thought it might find the langauge in the path but doesn't not automaticly set it, but debuging req, i18n returns 'en' on language, what am i doing wrong?

**Here is the code of related to i18n:**

setting-up i18next app.js:

```
var i18n = require('i18next');
i18n.init({
  ignoreRoutes: ['images/', 'public/', 'css/', 'js/'],
  supportedLngs: ['en', 'ee'],
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  //detectLngQS: 'lang', // ?lang=ee
  detectLngFromPath: 1,
  forceDetectLngFromPath: true,
  detectLngFromHeaders: false,
  useCookie: false,
  //cookieName: 'interspace-lang-cookie', // default 'i18next'
  debug: true,
});
```

later in app.js reference the route file:

```
i18n.registerAppHelper(app);
app.use(i18n.handle);

var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);
```

/routes/index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:lang', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Hello' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at running sample (test): https://github.com/jamuhl/i18next-node/blob/master/test/i18next.detectLanguage.spec.js#L12

-> index starting from 0 - try setting `detectLngFromPath=0`

Comment: Kinda funny, but found out the problem was using 'ee' to identify estonia, instead of 'et', now everything seems to work, but looking through the test it helped find the problem.